# Assign onclick to a function issue

Tags: javascript, html, function, button, onclick

My code to add a `onclick` function is as follows`newbutton.onclick = whoWon(this.id)`

Other Relevant Code

```
var winner;

function whoWon(name){
   winner = name
}
```

My problem is that the onclick when i try to assign it executes and doesn't add the onclick.  I know this because when I create the new button the variable winner is always the most recent button created.  Also when I inspect the element in google chrome the only thing that is assigned is the ID and the Class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`newbutton.onclick = whoWon(this.id)` will actually call the `whoWon` function.

You need to pass the `whoWon` as is, without calling it and bind it the `this.id`. This should do the trick:

```
newbutton.onclick = whoWon.bind(null, this.id)
```

Or as mentioned by @styfle in the comments, you could create an anonymous function:

```
newbutton.onclick = () => whoWon(this.id)
```

Comment: Or you can assign an anonymous function with `newbutton.onclick = () => whoWon(this.id)`

Comment: I Have tried both of these sugestions but it still doesn't work.  Is the button being in a table row an issue?

Comment: I made another variable which contains the innerHTML of the button which was the same as the id and that worked

Answer (score 1):

Your code `newbutton.onclick = whoWon(this.id)` executes `whoWom(this.id)` and assigns the result of it (which is `undefined` in this case) to `newbutton.onclick`.

What you really should be using is:

```
newbutton.addEventListener('click', whoWon);
```

From there you can access the equivalent of `this.id` with `event.target.id`